# location of .erlang.cookie in ejabberd docker is missing

Tags: ejabberd

I am running ejabberd using this docker image "https://github.com/processone/docker-ejabberd/tree/master/ecs".

Wondering which is the path for .erlang.cookie inside the container? I was trying to setup cluster in different host.

I can't find it in /home/ejabberd location. Tried setting environment variable ERLANG_COOKIE while running docker still can't find it in /home/ejabberd location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is in `$HOME` directory when login to the container as `root user`, In my case `/home/ejabberd`. The file is hidden use `ls -a` to list it.

To login as root user to the container use `--user root` while `docker exec`

Answer (score 1):

You already found where the erlang cookie file is generated and available.

Alternatively, you can use the ERLANG_COOKIE environment variable to set the cookie value, and don't care about the file. See https://github.com/processone/docker-ejabberd/tree/master/ecs#clustering-example